# Kaniko executes Dockerfile instructions within the ci image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, containers, kaniko

I have copied the kaniko executor from the `gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug` in our custom image, our ci image looks like below

```
FROM gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug AS kaniko

FROM custom-registry/ubuntu:22.04

COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/ /kaniko/
ENV SSL_CERT_DIR /kaniko/ssl/certs
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/bin:/kaniko

.
. 
.
rest of the docker file
```

This is how I built my `ci` image. This ci image has `aws cli` also installed.

The problem is now when I use this ci image to execute the kaniko command
`/kaniko/executor     --dockerfile=Dockerfile --verbosity info --insecure --skip-tls-verify --force --destination=custom-registry/app:v0.1  --context=./`
The `Dockerfile` for `app` pulls the `ubuntu base image` & in addition to including the application dependencies it also installs `aws cli` as below

```
FROM custom-registry/ubuntu:22.04

RUN cd  /opt && \
    curl -sk "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install 
.
.
rest of the app dockerfile
```

But now eventhough the `ubuntu:22.04` doesn't have `aws cli` installed, `kaniko` command fails with `aws cli` already installed

```
 ./aws/install
Found preexisting AWS CLI installation: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current. Please rerun install script with --update flag
```

From what I understood, the `RUN` or any instruction in the `Dockerfile` is ran on the `kaniko image` directly. Why is this so?
How can I bypass this & get it installed directly in the base image that I have configured in `FROM` instruction.

I am aware that kaniko's officialy recommendation is to use the kaniko executor image itself, but since due to our corporate policy I am compelled to use our own custom image.